# Leave both SplitViewController from inside TabBarController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` inside a `UITabBarController`. Now, when I click a button, I want to leave these two Controllers behind and show another ViewController.

I am using this code:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    RegistrationViewController *vc = (RegistrationViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationViewController"];
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

Now, the `RegistrationViewController` pops up for a second but immediately disappears. How can I make `RegistrationViewController` stay?

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple docs:

> **Note**
>
> "... Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in most cases. Split view controllers are normally installed at the root of your app’s window. For tips and guidance about ways to implement your interface, see iOS Human Interface Guidelines."

You may get unexpected behavior (and rejected App Store submission) if you do otherwise.

You may be better served by embedding the `UITabBarController` as the Detail View Controller of the `UISplitViewController.`

Set the `UISplitViewController` `.preferredDisplayMode` to `.primaryHidden` (hides the left 1/3 'Master View', giving you full screen presentation of the `UITabBarController`.) You can then call `showDetailViewController` to present your `RegistrationViewController`.

FWIW, I have had good luck embedding two `UINavigationController`'s as 'Master' and 'Detail' of the `UISplitViewController`, and pushing and popping views to the navigation stack to display. Great tutorial here, with more discussion about benefits of using NavControllers:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Some Swift code:

(Using the above approach, with nav controllers as Master and Detail, showing only Detail View of the `UISplitViewController,` then presenting a new view controller as the Detail View.)

```
@IBAction func createAccountButtonSelected(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let registrationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationViewController") as! RegistrationViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationVC, animated: true)
}
```

In another case, I wanted to reset the navigation stacks for both Master and Detail views of the `UISplitViewController` (from the Detail View Controller):

```
let firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    // Get a reference the the Master View nav controller
let masterNav = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    // Set desired VC's as nav stack RootViewControllers        
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([matchVC], animated: true)
masterNav.setViewControllers([masterMatchTableView], animated: true)
```